# Google Groups Post Permissions

Tags: permissions, google-groups-api

I have used both GAM and the Google Groups API to script the following:

"whoCanPostMessage":"ALL_IN_DOMAIN_CAN_POST"

By default, this also includes ALL_MEMBERS_CAN_POST.

I DO_NOT want members to be able to post.

Is there any way to exclude All_Members when you want ALL_IN_DOMAIN??

(I know I could do it manually, one-by-one, through the Google Admin Console, but that would be very tedious and time consuming)

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

According to the Groups Settings API [documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/groups-settings/v1/reference/groups#resource), possible settings for this attribute are:

NONE_CAN_POST
ALL_MANAGERS_CAN_POST
ALL_MEMBERS_CAN_POST 
ALL_IN_DOMAIN_CAN_POST
ANYONE_CAN_POST

as you've seen in testing, setting this attribute to ALL_IN_DOMAIN_CAN_POST also adds ALL_MEMBERS_CAN_POST. There's no way to select ALL_IN_DOMAIN and not ALL_MEMBERS via the API.